# Unable to get the number of links on a webpage using HTTPUNIT?

Tags: java, html-parsing, http-unit

I have started learning HTTPUNIT and found one basic example.

In this example it will visit this [site](http://www.meterware.com).
And it will search for the link containing [HTTPUNIT](http://www.httpunit.org/).  And it will print the number of links on the [HTTPUNIT](http://www.httpunit.org/). I tried this example on my machine and it works.

```
        WebConversation wc = new WebConversation();
        WebRequest request = new GetMethodWebRequest( "http://www.meterware.com" );
        WebResponse response = wc.getResponse( request );
        WebLink httpunitLink = response.getFirstMatchingLink( WebLink.MATCH_CONTAINED_TEXT, "HttpUnit" );
        response = httpunitLink.click();
        System.out.println( "The HttpUnit main page contains " + response.getLinks().length + " links" );
```

Now i have changed the code to

```
  WebConversation wc = new WebConversation();
  WebRequest request = new GetMethodWebRequest( "http://www.google.com" );
  WebResponse response = wc.getResponse( request );
  WebLink httpunitLink = response.getFirstMatchingLink( WebLink.MATCH_CONTAINED_TEXT, "News" );
  response = httpunitLink.click();
  System.out.println( "The HttpUnit main page contains " + response.getLinks().length + " links" );
```

And now it is giving the error below.

```
ConversionError: The undefined value has no properties. (httpunit; line 4)
```

Why it is not able to visit google news and get the number of links?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google home page is rendered from JavaScript.

HTTPUNIT has [partial support for JavaScript](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq.html#javascript). If you need to test pages with heavy JavaScript, take a look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: More specifically, "WebDriver", which is part of Selenium.

Comment: @Devon Is it something like QTP? ""Quick Test Professional"

Comment: @vikii Conceptually similar. Selenium Webdriver hooks into the browser to let you control its interaction with a website.

Comment: @Devon Can you provide me an example where i can see the example? I have never heard of Selenium Webdriver.So dont know where to begin with.

Comment: @vikiii I won't have time until later in the week, but I'll update this with an example. Meanwhile, have a read through http;//seleniumhq.org/docs

Comment: @Devon thanks.i will do it.Let me know when you have develop an example.It will be good if you take an example of www.google.com itself.